# Shared instance swift

Tags: swift

How would you write the following in swift?

```
static ClassName* singleCommon = nil;
+ (ClassName*)sharedInstance {
    @synchronized(singleCommon) {
        if(!singleCommon) singleCommon = [[ClassName alloc] init];
    }
    return singleCommon;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution is:

```
class Singleton {
    class var sharedInstance: Singleton {
        struct Static {
            static var instance: Singleton?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = Singleton()
        }

        return Static.instance!
    }
}
```

Solution and explanation coming from:
[http://code.martinrue.com](http://code.martinrue.com/posts/the-singleton-pattern-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

I Usually use sharedInstance in Swift like this:

```
private let _sharedInstance = SomeClass()

class SomeClass: NSObject {

    class var sharedInstance: SomeClass {
        get {
            return _sharedInstance
        }
    }

}
```

Here is a blogpost discussing this question:
http://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/

Comment: it is smell bad, your `_sharedInstance` is out of class and it can conflict with other implementation if they resolve do same you do here